# Will a slice allocate a new memory space when len is changed?

Tags: go, pointers, memory, slice

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := make([]int,3,4)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("before len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p",len(arr), cap(arr), &arr))
    arr = arr[1:2]
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("after len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p",len(arr), cap(arr), &arr))
}
```

```
before len:3,cap:4, address:0xc0000a6020
after len:1,cap:3, address:0xc0000a6020
```

the address before and after the slicing is the same.

My question is, will the slice allocate a new memory when its len  is changed from 3 to 1.

Because slice have three-element, Data uintptr, Len int, Cap int
If one of them changes, My guess is that a new slice will be generated on the memory, is that true?

Comment: No. The slice always points to the same backing array, which never changes size, so there is never a need to reallocate memory.

Comment: If you're referring to the slice header itself... `&arr` will always point to the same memory, that being the address of the local variable `arr`.

Comment: I wonder why is this downvoted? Seems like a genuine ask.

Answer (score 4):

A slice will reallocate its Data if it grows larger than its capacity, but the header will not move.  You would see this with &arr[0].  If you copy a slice, you get a new, different header, but they will share data, until the original or copy's data is reallocated.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := make([]int,3,4)
    arrCopy := arr
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("before   len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p, data:%p",len(arr), cap(arr), &arr, &arr[0]))
    arr = arr[1:2]
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("after    len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p, data:%p",len(arr), cap(arr), &arr, &arr[0]))
    arr = append(arr, arrCopy...)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("appended len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p, data:%p",len(arr), cap(arr), &arr, &arr[0]))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("arrCopy  len:%d,cap:%d, address:%p, data:%p",len(arrCopy), cap(arrCopy), &arrCopy, &arrCopy[0]))
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/Rtvt16DH_tj)